# Orthogonal Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

The orthogonal Grassmannian $OG(k,n)$ is the set of all isotropic $k$ dimensional subspaces of a $n$ dimensional subspaces with respect to a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form. Is it isomorphic to a $SO(n)/P_k$ where $P_k$ is the maximal parabolic subgroup with respect to a simple root ?

Comment: I would almost say yes, up to the point that it is $SO(n)/P_k$ where $P_k$ is parabolic (that is a very standard one-line argument using Witt's theorem). However, $P_k$ is not maximal in general, so could you clarify what "maximal with respect to a simple root" means?

Comment: The maximal parabolic associated to the simple root $\alpha_k$ is the subgroup generated by the Borel subgroup $B$ and $\{n_{\alpha}: \alpha \in S \setminus {\alpha_k}\}$ where $S$ is the set of simple roots and $n_{\alpha}$ is a representative of $s_{\alpha}$ in $N_G(T)$.

Comment: Did you write down the stabilizer of a space in $OG(k,n)$ in matrix notation? It is a block triangular matrix with two blocks, so it should contain every Coxeter generator but one. Sorry, my knowledge of the general terminology, without writing it down with matrices, is not good enough to answer in general.